# Using Contacts in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace

It's possible to insert contact from contacts.google.com to document in Google Docs in Google Workspace?

I manage lot of contacts in Gmail, with phones, email and addresses, like as typical address book.

We use Google Docs as place to write and store typical (printed) letters.
I would like insert address with postal, street, etc. to my letter.

Comment: Do you need to add the address on a specific part of the Google Doc? Are you using a master file with placeholders where the address will be added? Do you need any other information apart from the address?

Comment: @kicaj if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76418548/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @GiselleValladares It's exactly as you wrote.

Comment: @LorenaGomez Really, we need programing language for simple task like this?

Comment: @kicaj, to do this type of automatic changes, yes, since there is not a native option to do this change. The most we can do in Google is to use Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of what you can do, since you didn't specify the programming language. I created a sample code with Python, but I'm adding the list of methods that I used, so you can apply it to any other language.

First, you need to make sure that you have the complete email address for the user.

e.g.

[image: Address for the contact]

And for this example, I created a Google Doc with some placeholders, which will be replaced later on with the code.

[image: Google Doc Master doc]

*Note: You can make a copy of the Google Doc using the Google Drive API, with the method `files().copy`. You can review a sample on how to do this [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#copy_an_existing_document).*

For the People API (Contacts API is being deprecated), I used the method [people.searchContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchContacts), so I can get the `resourceName` for this contact.

*Note: You can search the contact by name, or email address*

After that, I use the method [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get), with the `resourceName` I got from `people.searchContacts` response.

Lastly, I use the [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#request-body) request method, with the [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest) to replace the placeholders with the information I got from the People API.

Here is the sample code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
DOCUMENT_ID = the_document_ID


def main(contact_to_search):

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service_contact = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        service_doc = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)


        # Search for the user, for this example I use the email address of the user.
        # This is to get the 'resourceName', which it will be necesary for the get method 

        search_contact_resource_Name = service_contact.people().searchContacts(
            query=contact_to_search,
            readMask='names'
        ).execute()

        resource = search_contact_resource_Name.get('results', [])[
            0].get('person')
        
        resource_Name = resource.get('resourceName')
        contact_name = resource.get('names')[0].get('displayName')

        # Use the get method to obtain the address

        get_contact_address = service_contact.people().get(
            resourceName=resource_Name,
            personFields='addresses'
        ).execute()

        # filter the work address of the user

        if get_contact_address.get('addresses') != None:
            values = get_contact_address['addresses']
            for value in values:

                # you can change the filter to 'home' or 'other'
                if value.get('type') == 'work':
                    contact_address = value.get('formattedValue')
        
        # In case there is no address available in the contact
        else:
            contact_address = 'No work address available'


        # JSON request body to replace the place holders
        # we got from the contact   

        add_text_body = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "replaceAllText": {
                        "replaceText": contact_name,
                        "containsText": {
                            "matchCase": True,
                            "text": "{{ Name }}"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "replaceAllText": {
                        "replaceText": contact_address,
                        "containsText": {
                            "matchCase": True,
                            "text": "{{ Address }}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

        # replace the information in the Google Doc. 

        document = service_doc.documents().batchUpdate(
            documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body=add_text_body).execute()

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('testuser_for_contacts@domain.com')
```

And, it will work like this:

[image: result]